# extract and split the content of a specific column into a new csv file with new columnser

Tags: python-3.x, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have a column (second column called second_column) in my csv file which represents à list of characters and its positions as follow: 
the column called `character_position`

Each line of  this column  contains a list of character_position . overall l have 300 lines in this column each with list of character position

```
character_position = [['1', 1890, 1904, 486, 505, '8', 1905, 1916, 486, 507, '4', 1919, 1931, 486, 505, '1', 1935, 1947, 486, 505, '7', 1950, 1962, 486, 505, '2', 1965, 1976, 486, 505, '9', 1980, 1992, 486, 507, '6', 1995, 2007, 486, 505, '/', 2010, 2022, 484, 508, '4', 2025, 2037, 486, 505, '8', 2040, 2052, 486, 505, '3', 2057, 2067, 486, 507, '3', 2072, 2082, 486, 505, '0', 2085, 2097, 486, 507, '/', 2100, 2112, 484, 508, 'Q', 2115, 2127, 486, 507, '1', 2132, 2144, 486, 505, '7', 2147, 2157, 486, 505, '9', 2162, 2174, 486, 505, '/', 2175, 2189, 484, 508, 'C', 2190, 2204, 487, 505, '4', 2207, 2219, 486, 505, '1', 2241, 2253, 486, 505, '/', 2255, 2268, 484, 508, '1', 2271, 2285, 486, 507, '5', 2288, 2297, 486, 505], ['D', 2118, 2132, 519, 535, '.', 2138, 2144, 529, 534, '2', 2150, 2162, 516, 535, '0', 2165, 2177, 516, 535, '4', 2180, 2192, 516, 534, '7', 2196, 2208, 516, 534, '0', 2210, 2223, 514, 535, '1', 2226, 2238, 516, 534, '8', 2241, 2253, 514, 534, '2', 2256, 2267, 514, 535, '4', 2270, 2282, 516, 534, '0', 2285, 2298, 514, 535]]
```

each character has for values : left, top, right, bottom. For instance 
character `'1'` has left=1890, top=1904, right=486, bottom=505.

l want to create another csv file with five columns :

```
column 1:  character, column 2 : left , column 3 : top, column 4 : right, column 5 : bottom.
```

Here is what l have done :

```
import pandas as pd :
character= []
left_position = []
right_position = []
top_position=[]
bottom_position []
temp_df = pd.DataFrame({'character': position_char, 'left': left_position, 'top': top_position, 'right' : right_position,'bottom': bottom_position})
temp_df.to_csv('character_position.csv')
```

my file that contains the column of characters_position in one column can be accessed as follow :

```
import csv
with open('list_characters.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        content = list(row[i] for i in second_column)
```

How can l extract and split the content of the `second_column` of the file `list_characters.csv` into a new csv file `character_position.csv` with five column ?

My first row of the column character_position is as follow :

```
[['m', 38, 104, 2456, 2492, 'i', 40, 102, 2442, 2448, 'i', 40, 100, 2402, 2410, 'l', 40, 102, 2372, 2382, 'm', 40, 102, 2312, 2358, 'u', 40, 102, 2292, 2310, 'i', 40, 104, 2210, 2260, 'l', 40, 104, 2180, 2208, 'i', 40, 104, 2140, 2166, 'l', 40, 104, 2124, 2134]]
```

My second row of the column character_position is as follow :

```
[['A', 73, 91, 373, 394, 'D', 93, 112, 373, 396, 'R', 115, 133, 373, 396, 'E', 136, 153, 373, 396, 'S', 156, 172, 373, 396, 'S', 175, 192, 373, 396, 'E', 195, 211, 373, 396, 'D', 222, 241, 373, 396, 'E', 244, 261, 373, 396, 'L', 272, 285, 375, 396, 'I', 288, 293, 375, 396, 'V', 296, 314, 375, 396, 'R', 317, 334, 373, 396, 'A', 334, 354, 375, 396, 'I', 357, 360, 373, 396, 'S', 365, 381, 373, 396, 'O', 384, 405, 373, 396, 'N', 408, 425, 373, 394]]
```

and here is how l access to character position column :

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer='list_characters.csv', header=None, usecols=[1], names=['character_position])

df
                                     character_position
    0   [['m', 38, 104, 2456, 2492, 'i', 40, 102, 2442...
    1   [['.', 203, 213, 191, 198, '3', 235, 262, 131,...
    2   [['A', 275, 347, 147, 239, 'M', 363, 465, 145,...
    3   [['A', 73, 91, 373, 394, 'D', 93, 112, 373, 39...
    4   [['D', 454, 473, 663, 685, 'O', 474, 495, 664,...
    5   [['A', 108, 129, 727, 751, 'V', 129, 150, 727,...
    6   [['N', 34, 51, 949, 970, '/', 52, 61, 948, 970...
    7   [['S', 1368, 1401, 43, 85, 'A', 1406, 1446, 43...
    8   [['S', 1437, 1457, 112, 138, 'o', 1458, 1476, ...
    9   [['h', 1686, 1703, 315, 339, 't', 1706, 1715, ...
    10  [['N', 1331, 1349, 370, 391, 'C', 1361, 1379, ...
    11  [['N', 1758, 1775, 370, 391, 'D', 1785, 1803, ...
    12  [['D', 2166, 2184, 370, 391, 'A', 2186, 2205, ...
    13  [['2', 1395, 1415, 427, 454, '0', 1416, 1434, ...
    14  [['I', 1533, 1545, 487, 541, 'I', 1548, 1551, ...
    15  [['P', 1659, 1677, 490, 514, '2', 1680, 1697, ...
    16  [['1', 1890, 1904, 486, 505, '8', 1905, 1916, ...
    17  [['B', 1344, 1361, 583, 607, 'O', 1364, 1386, ...
    18  [['B', 1548, 1580, 979, 1015, 'T', 1586, 1619,...
    19  [['Q', 169, 190, 1291, 1312, 'U', 192, 210, 12...
    20  [['1', 296, 305, 1492, 1516, 'S', 339, 357, 14...
    21  [['G', 339, 362, 1815, 1840, 'S', 365, 384, 18...
    22  [['2', 1440, 1455, 2047, 2073, '9', 1458, 1475...
    23  [['R', 339, 360, 2137, 2163, 'e', 363, 378, 21...
    24  [['R', 339, 360, 1860, 1885, 'e', 363, 380, 18...
    25  [['0', 1266, 1283, 1951, 1977, ',', 1287, 1290...
    26  [['1', 2207, 2217, 1492, 1515, '0', 2225, 2240...
    27  [['1', 2364, 2382, 1552, 1585], [], ['E', 2369...
    28                    [['S', 2369, 2382, 1833, 1866]]
    29  [['0', 2243, 2259, 1951, 1977, '0', 2271, 2288...
    ..                                                ...
    70  [['1', 296, 305, 1492, 1516, 'S', 339, 357, 14...
    71  [['G', 339, 362, 1815, 1840, 'S', 365, 384, 18...
    72  [['2', 1440, 1455, 2047, 2073, '9', 1458, 1475...
    73  [['R', 339, 360, 2137, 2163, 'e', 363, 378, 21...
    74  [['R', 339, 360, 1860, 1885, 'e', 363, 380, 18...
    75  [['0', 1266, 1283, 1951, 1977, ',', 1287, 1290...
    76  [['1', 2207, 2217, 1492, 1515, '0', 2225, 2240...
    77  [['1', 2364, 2382, 1552, 1585], [], ['E', 2369...
    78                    [['S', 2369, 2382, 1833, 1866]]
    79  [['0', 2243, 2259, 1951, 1977, '0', 2271, 2288...
    80  [['0', 2243, 2259, 2227, 2253, '0', 2271, 2286...
    81  [['D', 76, 88, 2580, 2596, 'é', 91, 100, 2580,...
    82  [['ü', 1474, 1489, 2586, 2616, '3', 1541, 1557...
    83  [['E', 1440, 1461, 2670, 2697, 'U', 1466, 1488...
    84  [['2', 1685, 1703, 2670, 2697, '.', 1707, 1712...
    85  [['1', 2202, 2213, 2668, 2695, '3', 2220, 2237...
    86                       [['c', 88, 118, 2872, 2902]]
    87  [['N', 127, 144, 2889, 2910, 'D', 156, 175, 28...
    88  [['E', 108, 129, 3144, 3172, 'C', 133, 156, 31...
    89  [['5', 108, 126, 3204, 3231, '0', 129, 147, 32...
    90                                               [[]]
    91  [['1', 480, 492, 3202, 3229, '6', 500, 518, 32...
    92  [['P', 217, 234, 3337, 3360, 'A', 235, 255, 33...
    93                                               [[]]
    94  [['I', 954, 963, 2892, 2934, 'M', 969, 1011, 2...
    95  [['E', 1385, 1407, 2970, 2998, 'U', 1410, 1433...
    96  [['T', 2067, 2084, 2889, 2911, 'O', 2088, 2106...
    97  [['1', 2201, 2213, 2970, 2997, '6', 2219, 2238...
    98  [['M', 1734, 1755, 3246, 3267, 'O', 1758, 1779...
    99  [['L', 923, 935, 3411, 3430, 'A', 941, 957, 34...
```

when l try :

```
df['character_position'][1]
"[['.', 203, 213, 191, 198, '3', 235, 262, 131, 198]]"

df['character_position'][2]
"[['A', 275, 347, 147, 239, 'M', 363, 465, 145, 239, 'S', 485, 549, 145, 243, 'U', 569, 631, 145, 241, 'N', 657, 733, 145, 239]]"
```

then apply as you said :

```
df=pd.DataFrame(np.array(list(chain.from_iterable( df['character_position'][2]))).reshape(-1,5), 
                   columns=cols)
```

l get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 127 into shape (5)
```

in order to check l did this :

```
Y=df['character_position'][2]

 "[['A', 275, 347, 147, 239, 'M', 363, 465, 145, 239, 'S', 485, 549, 145, 243, 'U', 569, 631, 145, 241, 'N', 657, 733, 145, 239]]"
```

then :

```
Y[0] gives '['
```

But we are supposed to get

```
['A', 275, 347, 147, 239, 'M', 363, 465, 145, 239, 'S', 485, 549, 145, 243, 'U', 569, 631, 145, 241, 'N', 657, 733, 145, 239]
```

since it's a nested list.

l think we need a loop which iterate the whole rows of that column :

```
df.ix[:len(df)]
 df=pd.DataFrame(np.array(list(chain.from_iterable( df['character_position'].ix[:len(df)]))).reshape(-1,5), 
                       columns=cols)
```

After executing the following code :

```
cols = ['char','left','top','right','bottom']
df1 = df.character_position.str.strip('[]').str.split(', ', expand=True)
df1.columns = [df1.columns % 5, df1.columns // 5]
df1 = df1.stack().reset_index(drop=True)
df1.columns = cols
df1[cols[1:]] = df1[cols[1:]].astype(int)
```

l got this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3054, in astype
    raise_on_error=raise_on_error, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3189, in astype
    return self.apply('astype', dtype=dtype, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3056, in apply
    applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 461, in astype
    values=values, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 504, in _astype
    values = _astype_nansafe(values.ravel(), dtype, copy=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/types/cast.py", line 534, in _astype_nansafe
    return lib.astype_intsafe(arr.ravel(), dtype).reshape(arr.shape)
  File "pandas/lib.pyx", line 980, in pandas.lib.astype_intsafe (pandas/lib.c:17409)
  File "pandas/src/util.pxd", line 93, in util.set_value_at_unsafe (pandas/lib.c:72104)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "['E'"
```

The code runs until df1.columns = cols

```
when l print df1 :

    print(df1)
it works. The l saved it in a csv file.

    df1.to_csv('positions.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need first convert `strings` to `lists` with [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html).

Then use chain for falttening values and reshape. Last if necessary convert columns to int.

```
from  itertools import chain

#temporaly display content
with pd.option_context('display.max_colwidth', 120):
    print (df)
                                      character_position
0  [['m', 38, 104, 2456, 2492, 'i', 40, 102, 2442, 222]]
1  [['.', 203, 213, 191, 198, '3', 235, 262, 131, 3333]]
2  [['A', 275, 347, 147, 239, 'M', 363, 465, 145, 3334]]
3       [['A', 73, 91, 373, 394, 'D', 93, 112, 373, 39]]
4    [['D', 454, 473, 663, 685, 'O', 474, 495, 664, 33]]
5   [['A', 108, 129, 727, 751, 'V', 129, 150, 727, 444]]

df.character_position = df.character_position.str.strip('[]').str.split(', ')

cols = ['char','left','top','right','bottom']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array(list(chain.from_iterable(df.character_position))).reshape(-1,5), 
                   columns=cols)
df1[cols[1:]] = df1[cols[1:]].astype(int)
print (df1)

0   'm'    38  104   2456    2492
1   'i'    40  102   2442     222
2   '.'   203  213    191     198
3   '3'   235  262    131    3333
4   'A'   275  347    147     239
5   'M'   363  465    145    3334
6   'A'    73   91    373     394
7   'D'    93  112    373      39
8   'D'   454  473    663     685
9   'O'   474  495    664      33
10  'A'   108  129    727     751
11  'V'   129  150    727     444
```

Another solution with `MultiIndex` and reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
cols = ['char','left','top','right','bottom']
df1 = df.character_position.str.strip('[]').str.split(', ', expand=True)
df1.columns = [df1.columns % 5, df1.columns // 5]
df1 = df1.stack().reset_index(drop=True)
df1.columns = cols
df1[cols[1:]] = df1[cols[1:]].astype(int)
print (df1)
   char  left  top  right  bottom
0   'm'    38  104   2456    2492
1   'i'    40  102   2442     222
2   '.'   203  213    191     198
3   '3'   235  262    131    3333
4   'A'   275  347    147     239
5   'M'   363  465    145    3334
6   'A'    73   91    373     394
7   'D'    93  112    373      39
8   'D'   454  473    663     685
9   'O'   474  495    664      33
10  'A'   108  129    727     751
11  'V'   129  150    727     444
```

Comment: what do you mean by character_position[0] ? my csv file where the character positions is 'list_characters.csv' and the column is called character_position. l'm wandering how do you access to character_position column of list_characters.csv

Comment: I use `[0]` becasue  `character_position` is nested list.

Comment: but if is not nested, simply remove `[0]`.

Comment: @jerzael , l added the structure of my rows in character_position column see the rows

Comment: thanks, l updated also my code. however' df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(list(chain.from_iterable(character_position))).reshape(-1,5), 
                   columns=cols) ' doesn't work for me. since in each row l have a list of character_position. 100 rows of character position so  l need to iterate through the 100 rows. and l a reach  character_position column as follow 'df = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer='list_characters.csv', header=None, usecols=[1], names=['character_position]) ' check the print of my df

Comment: Please check my update and improvements. hope it's more clear

Comment: I see problem, give me a some time.

Comment: l tried your update but l stack at the line : df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array(list(chain.from_iterable(df.character_position))).reshape(-1,5), 
                   columns=cols)  l got this error ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 20496 into shape (5)

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, the second solution seems to work but l get an error when executing this line 'df1[cols[1:]] = df1[cols[1:]].astype(int)' return lib.astype_intsafe(arr.ravel(), dtype).reshape(arr.shape)
  File "pandas/lib.pyx", line 980, in pandas.lib.astype_intsafe (pandas/lib.c:17409)
  File "pandas/src/util.pxd", line 93, in util.set_value_at_unsafe (pandas/lib.c:72104)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "['E'"

Comment: It only convert values to int. Is it necessary? Simply omit it.

Comment: not necessary thanks. but there is some bugs :  '5' 962 979 727 751]. Why 751] l'm supposed to get 751. l have also some of character '[N' rather than 'N'

Comment: sorry for the second case it is ['N' not '[ N' and l'm supposed to get something like 'N'

Comment: Unfortunately there is problem with data. But for remove `[`maybe help add white space to strip like `strip('[ ]')`

Comment: l can keep it simple . l go through all the columns and if l encounter [ or ] l remove it in my csv file. what is the most efficient and fast way to do that since l have lots of data ?

Comment: [] are only in first or last column? If yes, use boolean indexing. `df = df[~df['char'].str.contains('[')]`' It remove all rows where in column char is `[`. For last column similar. `df = df[~df['bottom'].str.contains(']')]`'

Comment: df = df[~df['char'].str.contains('[')] returns     source.tell() - here)
sre_constants.error: unterminated character set at position 0

Comment: and df = df[~df['bottom'].str.contains(']')] returns     arr = operator.inv(_values_from_object(self))
TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'NoneType'

Comment: I was on phone, so untested. So need escape `[]` - need `df1 = df1[~(df1['char'].str.contains('\[') | df1['bottom'].str.contains(']'))]`

Comment: but for char [ l have it before ' ' as follow ['N'